Navegação só retorna undefined - React + Typescript + MUI
Olá. Sou iniciante com React e Typescript. Estou tentando desenvolver um menu lateral com estrutura em árvore baseado na biblioteca MUI. Ao tentar navegar entre rotas clicando em um dos itens do menu, utilizando o useNavigate e atribuindo uma propriedade 'to?: string' à interface do componente, só estou recebendo 'undefined' no retorno do 'onclick'. Não estou entendendo o motivo de estar com esse retorno, já que estou atribuindo o valor desejado ao item a ser clicado. Mesmo tornando a propriedade obrigatória, não tenho retorno do valor dessa propriedade.


import { ElementType, HTMLAttributes, Ref, forwardRef } from "react";
import clsx from "clsx";
import { styled, useTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import { SvgIconProps } from "@mui/material/SvgIcon";
import {
  TreeItem2Content,
  TreeItem2IconContainer,
  TreeItem2Root,
  TreeItem2GroupTransition,
} from "@mui/x-tree-view/TreeItem2";
import {
  unstable_useTreeItem2 as useTreeItem,
  UseTreeItem2Parameters,
} from "@mui/x-tree-view/useTreeItem2";
import { TreeItem2Provider } from "@mui/x-tree-view/TreeItem2Provider";
import { TreeItem2Icon } from "@mui/x-tree-view/TreeItem2Icon";
import { SimpleTreeView } from "@mui/x-tree-view/SimpleTreeView";
import ArrowDropDownIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ArrowDropDown";
import ArrowRightIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ArrowRight";
import {
  LocalHospitalRounded,
  LocationCity,
  LocationCityTwoTone,
  People,
  PeopleAltOutlined,
  StarBorder,
} from "@mui/icons-material";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

declare module "react" {
  interface CSSProperties {
    "--tree-view-color"?: string;
    "--tree-view-bg-color"?: string;
  }
}

interface IListaItemArvoreProps
  extends Omit<UseTreeItem2Parameters, "rootRef">,
  HTMLAttributes<HTMLLIElement> {
  bgColor?: string;
  bgColorForDarkMode?: string;
  color?: string;
  colorForDarkMode?: string;
  labelIcon?: ElementType<SvgIconProps>;
  labelInfo?: string;
  to?: string;
}

const CustomTreeItemRoot = styled(TreeItem2Root)(({ theme }) => ({
  color: theme.palette.text.primary,
}));

const CustomTreeItemContent = styled(TreeItem2Content)(({ theme }) => ({
  marginBottom: theme.spacing(0.3),
  color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
  paddingRight: theme.spacing(1),
}));

const CustomTreeItemIconContainer = styled(TreeItem2IconContainer)(
  ({ theme }) => ({
    // marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
  })
);

const CustomTreeItemGroupTransition = styled(TreeItem2GroupTransition)(
  ({ theme }) => ({
    marginLeft: 0,
    [`& .content`]: {
      paddingLeft: theme.spacing(2),
    },
  })
);

const CustomTreeItem = forwardRef(function CustomTreeItem(
  props: IListaItemArvoreProps,
  ref: Ref<HTMLLIElement>
) {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const {
    id,
    itemId,
    label,
    disabled,
    children,
    bgColor,
    color,
    labelIcon: LabelIcon,
    labelInfo,
    colorForDarkMode,
    bgColorForDarkMode,
    ...other
  } = props;

  const {
    getRootProps,
    getContentProps,
    getIconContainerProps,
    getLabelProps,
    getGroupTransitionProps,
    status,
  } = useTreeItem({ id, itemId, children, label, disabled, rootRef: ref });

  const style = {
    "--tree-view-color":
      theme.palette.mode !== "dark" ? color : colorForDarkMode,
    "--tree-view-bg-color":
      theme.palette.mode !== "dark" ? bgColor : bgColorForDarkMode,
  };

  return (
    //@ts-ignore
    <TreeItem2Provider itemId={itemId}>
      <CustomTreeItemRoot {...getRootProps({ ...other, style })}>
        <CustomTreeItemContent
          {...getContentProps({
            className: clsx("content", {
              expanded: status.expanded,
              selected: status.selected,
              focused: status.focused,
            }),
          })}
        >
          <CustomTreeItemIconContainer {...getIconContainerProps()}>
            <TreeItem2Icon status={status} />
          </CustomTreeItemIconContainer>
          <Box
            sx={{
              display: "flex",
              flexGrow: 1,
              alignItems: "center",
              p: 0.5,
              pr: 0,
            }}
          >
            <Box component={LabelIcon} color="inherit" sx={{ mr: 1 }} />
            <Typography
              {...getLabelProps({
                variant: "body2",
                sx: { display: "flex", fontWeight: "inherit", flexGrow: 1 },
              })}
            />
            <Typography variant="caption" color="inherit">
              {labelInfo}
            </Typography>
          </Box>
        </CustomTreeItemContent>
        {children && (
          <CustomTreeItemGroupTransition {...getGroupTransitionProps()} />
        )}
      </CustomTreeItemRoot>
    </TreeItem2Provider>
  );
});

function EndIcon() {
  return <div style={{ width: 24 }} />;
};

export const ListaItemArvore: React.FC<IListaItemArvoreProps> = ({ to }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleClick = () => {
    // navigate("/hospitalar");
    console.log(to);
  };

  return (
    <SimpleTreeView
      slots={{
        expandIcon: ArrowRightIcon,
        collapseIcon: ArrowDropDownIcon,
        endIcon: EndIcon,
      }}
      sx={{ flexGrow: 1, maxWidth: 400, marginTop: 2 }}
    >
      <CustomTreeItem
        itemId="hospitalar"
        label="Hospitalar"
        labelIcon={LocalHospitalRounded}

      >
        <CustomTreeItem itemId="1" label="N1" to="/hospitalar" onClick={handleClick} />
        <CustomTreeItem itemId="2" label="N2" />
        <CustomTreeItem itemId="3" label="N3" />
        <CustomTreeItem itemId="4" label="N4" labelIcon={StarBorder}>
          <CustomTreeItem itemId="5" label="N5">
            <CustomTreeItem itemId="6" label="N6">
              <CustomTreeItem itemId="7" label="N7" />
            </CustomTreeItem>
          </CustomTreeItem>
        </CustomTreeItem>
      </CustomTreeItem>
      <CustomTreeItem itemId="pessoas" label="Pessoas" labelIcon={People}>
        <CustomTreeItem itemId="a" label="Na" />
        <CustomTreeItem itemId="b" label="Nb" />
        <CustomTreeItem itemId="c" label="Nc" />
        <CustomTreeItem itemId="d" label="Nd" labelIcon={PeopleAltOutlined}>
          <CustomTreeItem itemId="e" label="Ne">
            <CustomTreeItem itemId="f" label="Nf">
              <CustomTreeItem itemId="g" label="Ng" />
            </CustomTreeItem>
          </CustomTreeItem>
        </CustomTreeItem>
      </CustomTreeItem>
      <CustomTreeItem
        itemId="cidades"
        label="Cidades"
        labelIcon={LocationCityTwoTone}

      >
        <CustomTreeItem itemId="c1" label="Nc1" />
        <CustomTreeItem itemId="c2" label="Nc2" />
        <CustomTreeItem itemId="c3" label="Nc3" />
        <CustomTreeItem itemId="c4" label="Nc4" labelIcon={LocationCity}>
          <CustomTreeItem itemId="c5" label="Nc5">
            <CustomTreeItem itemId="c6" label="Nc6">
              <CustomTreeItem itemId="c7" label="Nc7" />
            </CustomTreeItem>
          </CustomTreeItem>
        </CustomTreeItem>
      </CustomTreeItem>
    </SimpleTreeView>
  );
};



inserir a descrição da imagem aqui

Parece que o problema está no fato de que a propriedade "to" não está sendo passada corretamente para o CustomTreeItem e, consequentemente, não está sendo capturada no handleClick.
Tente usando o código abaixo.
import { ElementType, HTMLAttributes, Ref, forwardRef } from "react";
import clsx from "clsx";
import { styled, useTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import { SvgIconProps } from "@mui/material/SvgIcon";
import {
  TreeItem2Content,
  TreeItem2IconContainer,
  TreeItem2Root,
  TreeItem2GroupTransition,
} from "@mui/x-tree-view/TreeItem2";
import {
  unstable_useTreeItem2 as useTreeItem,
  UseTreeItem2Parameters,
} from "@mui/x-tree-view/useTreeItem2";
import { TreeItem2Provider } from "@mui/x-tree-view/TreeItem2Provider";
import { TreeItem2Icon } from "@mui/x-tree-view/TreeItem2Icon";
import { SimpleTreeView } from "@mui/x-tree-view/SimpleTreeView";
import ArrowDropDownIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ArrowDropDown";
import ArrowRightIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ArrowRight";
import {
  LocalHospitalRounded,
  LocationCity,
  LocationCityTwoTone,
  People,
  PeopleAltOutlined,
  StarBorder,
} from "@mui/icons-material";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

declare module "react" {
  interface CSSProperties {
    "--tree-view-color"?: string;
    "--tree-view-bg-color"?: string;
  }
}

interface IListaItemArvoreProps
  extends Omit<UseTreeItem2Parameters, "rootRef">,
  HTMLAttributes<HTMLLIElement> {
  bgColor?: string;
  bgColorForDarkMode?: string;
  color?: string;
  colorForDarkMode?: string;
  labelIcon?: ElementType<SvgIconProps>;
  labelInfo?: string;
  to?: string;
}

const CustomTreeItemRoot = styled(TreeItem2Root)(({ theme }) => ({
  color: theme.palette.text.primary,
}));

const CustomTreeItemContent = styled(TreeItem2Content)(({ theme }) => ({
  marginBottom: theme.spacing(0.3),
  color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
  paddingRight: theme.spacing(1),
}));

const CustomTreeItemIconContainer = styled(TreeItem2IconContainer)(
  ({ theme }) => ({
    // marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
  })
);

const CustomTreeItemGroupTransition = styled(TreeItem2GroupTransition)(
  ({ theme }) => ({
    marginLeft: 0,
    [`& .content`]: {
      paddingLeft: theme.spacing(2),
    },
  })
);

const CustomTreeItem = forwardRef(function CustomTreeItem(
  props: IListaItemArvoreProps,
  ref: Ref<HTMLLIElement>
) {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const {
    id,
    itemId,
    label,
    disabled,
    children,
    bgColor,
    color,
    labelIcon: LabelIcon,
    labelInfo,
    colorForDarkMode,
    bgColorForDarkMode,
    to,
    ...other
  } = props;

  const {
    getRootProps,
    getContentProps,
    getIconContainerProps,
    getLabelProps,
    getGroupTransitionProps,
    status,
  } = useTreeItem({ id, itemId, children, label, disabled, rootRef: ref });

  const style = {
    "--tree-view-color":
      theme.palette.mode !== "dark" ? color : colorForDarkMode,
    "--tree-view-bg-color":
      theme.palette.mode !== "dark" ? bgColor : bgColorForDarkMode,
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    if (to) {
      navigate(to);
    }
  };

  return (
    <TreeItem2Provider itemId={itemId}>
      <CustomTreeItemRoot {...getRootProps({ ...other, style })}>
        <CustomTreeItemContent
          {...getContentProps({
            className: clsx("content", {
              expanded: status.expanded,
              selected: status.selected,
              focused: status.focused,
            }),
            onClick: handleClick,
          })}
        >
          <CustomTreeItemIconContainer {...getIconContainerProps()}>
            <TreeItem2Icon status={status} />
          </CustomTreeItemIconContainer>
          <Box
            sx={{
              display: "flex",
              flexGrow: 1,
              alignItems: "center",
              p: 0.5,
              pr: 0,
            }}
          >
            {LabelIcon && <Box component={LabelIcon} color="inherit" sx={{ mr: 1 }} />}
            <Typography
              {...getLabelProps({
                variant: "body2",
                sx: { display: "flex", fontWeight: "inherit", flexGrow: 1 },
              })}
            >
              {label}
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="caption" color="inherit">
              {labelInfo}
            </Typography>
          </Box>
        </CustomTreeItemContent>
        {children && (
          <CustomTreeItemGroupTransition {...getGroupTransitionProps()} />
        )}
      </CustomTreeItemRoot>
    </TreeItem2Provider>
  );
});

function EndIcon() {
  return <div style={{ width: 24 }} />;
};

export const ListaItemArvore: React.FC<IListaItemArvoreProps> = ({ to }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <SimpleTreeView
      slots={{
        expandIcon: ArrowRightIcon,
        collapseIcon: ArrowDropDownIcon,
        endIcon: EndIcon,
      }}
      sx={{ flexGrow: 1, maxWidth: 400, marginTop: 2 }}
    >
      <CustomTreeItem
        itemId="hospitalar"
        label="Hospitalar"
        labelIcon={LocalHospitalRounded}
      >
        <CustomTreeItem itemId="1" label="N1" to="/hospitalar" />
        <CustomTreeItem itemId="2" label="N2" />
        <CustomTreeItem itemId="3" label="N3" />
        <CustomTreeItem itemId="4" label="N4" labelIcon={StarBorder}>
          <CustomTreeItem itemId="5" label="N5">
            <CustomTreeItem itemId="6" label="N6">
              <CustomTreeItem itemId="7" label="N7" />
            </CustomTreeItem>
          </CustomTreeItem>
        </CustomTreeItem>
      </CustomTreeItem>
      <CustomTreeItem itemId="pessoas" label="Pessoas" labelIcon={People}>
        <CustomTreeItem itemId="a" label="Na" />
        <CustomTreeItem itemId="b" label="Nb" />
        <CustomTreeItem itemId="c" label="Nc" />
        <CustomTreeItem itemId="d" label="Nd" labelIcon={PeopleAltOutlined}>
          <CustomTreeItem itemId="e" label="Ne">
            <CustomTreeItem itemId="f" label="Nf">
              <CustomTreeItem itemId="g" label="Ng" />
            </CustomTreeItem>
          </CustomTreeItem>
        </CustomTreeItem>
      </CustomTreeItem>
      <CustomTreeItem
        itemId="cidades"
        label="Cidades"
        labelIcon={LocationCityTwoTone}
      >
        <CustomTreeItem itemId="c1" label="Nc1" />
        <CustomTreeItem itemId="c2" label="Nc2" />
        <CustomTreeItem itemId="c3" label="Nc3" />
        <CustomTreeItem itemId="c4" label="Nc4" labelIcon={LocationCity}>
          <CustomTreeItem itemId="c5" label="Nc5">
            <CustomTreeItem itemId="c6" label="Nc6">
              <CustomTreeItem itemId="c7" label="Nc7" />
            </CustomTreeItem>
          </CustomTreeItem>
        </CustomTreeItem>
      </CustomTreeItem>
    </SimpleTreeView>
  );
};



Show, deu certo! Agradeço a ajuda!

Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas na Central de Ajuda.
